# Copyright infringement for domain based on common keywords

Tags: domains, copyright, domain-extension

Suppose an adult website adult.com has a copyrighted the trademark Adult™‎. Can anyone register adult.ooo or adult.xyz or registering the domain name adult with any extension would be an infringement of the trade mark of the registered user.
Simply I mean to ask does registering one domain with .com extension and copyrighting it gives the owner copyright over all the extensions?
Same question for non-regular keyword domains like facebook.com with facebook.ooo etc.

Comment: Suppose Chemours has registered the trademark Teflon. Can anyone register teflon.ooo or teflon.xyz? Try it and watch the cease and desist letters come flooding in on really expensive letterhead from really expensive law firms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In broad strokes:

- You can't copyright a trademark:

  - Copyright applies to creative works. You get copyright by creating.
  - Trademarks have to be registered.
- "Adult" is (probably) too generic a term to be trademarkable.
- Registering a domain name is not the same as registering a trademark.
- Domain name registration is handled on a first come first served basis but can be be disputed. Ownership of trademarks and evidence that a domain name was registered in bad faith (e.g. to impersonate another site) are factors that are taken into account.